# Cant See Loaded contacts in Account Contacts in Sandbox

Tags: contact

I have loaded a CSV file for contacts for an account via Data Import Wizard. When I run a report the contacts are there.  When I try to view them via the account they are linked to they do not appear

Comment: Is your org sharing setting set to private? If yes, you need to share those records with your user.

Comment: Can you see report, it might have ticked hierarchy field ticked.